# AWS: How to configure Customer Managed Key to publish events from AWS config to encrypted SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-config

beginner question here. I would like to publish events from AWS Config service to the SNS topic - encrypted. **I already publish to SNS from various services, but in case of these, it is possible to use service principal in my Customer Managed Key statement.** So my CMK yml section looks like this

```
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Principal:
                    Service:
                      - sns.amazonaws.com
                      - cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
                      - cloudwatch.amazonaws.com
                Action:
                  - kms:Encrypt
                  - kms:Decrypt
                  - kms:ReEncrypt*
                  - kms:GenerateDataKey*
                Resource: "*"
```

I know that in order to publish from AWS Config, I cannot use service principal. In documentation, I read

> Other Amazon SNS event sources require you to provide an IAM role, as
> opposed to their service principal, in the KMS key policy.

But there is no example how this IAM role should be provided. Is it something like this?

> ```
>                Principal:
>                     Service:
>                       - sns.amazonaws.com
>                       - cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
>                       - cloudwatch.amazonaws.com
>                     AWS:
>                       - Role IAM
> ```

Also, I am not sure how this role shall look like. I can create a role which can publish to SNS and add it to CMK, but how can I link it to AWS Config and make sure this role is used to publish events? Could someone advice what should this role contain? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From [docsL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/iamrole-permissions.html#iam-role-policies-sns-topic):

> If you create or update a role with the console, AWS Config attaches the **AWSConfigRole** for you.

In my case, as I checked what I have, the full arn of the role is:

```
arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/aws-service-role/config.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForConfig
```

Therefore, in your CFN, the following can be tried:

```
Principal:
    Service:
      - sns.amazonaws.com
      - cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
      - cloudwatch.amazonaws.com
    AWS:
      - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/config.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForConfig"
```

Prior to this, you can check if the `AWSServiceRoleForConfig` actually exist for you.